# Centering all the components in jpanel

Tags: java, layout

I'm having a problem centering all the checkbox inside the panel I already tried using some layout for the panel however It doesn't match the output that I want. As you can see in the output it over-lapse both sides.

Here is my code

```
            total = new JLabel("Total: 0");
        compute = new JButton("Compute");
        exit = new JButton("exit");
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.gray);
        panel2 = new JPanel();
        panel2.setBackground(Color.blue);
        panel3 = new JPanel();
        panel3.setBackground(Color.gray);
        panel4 = new JPanel();
        panel4.setBackground(Color.blue);
        panel5 = new JPanel();
        panel5.setBackground(Color.gray);
        
        panel.add(beverages);
        panel.add(a1);panel.add(a2);panel.add(a3);panel.add(a4);panel.add(a5);
        panel.add(a6);panel.add(a7);panel.add(a8);panel.add(a9);panel.add(a10);
        add(panel);
        panel2.add(snacks);
        panel2.add(b1);panel2.add(b2);panel2.add(b3);panel2.add(b4);panel2.add(b5);
        panel2.add(b6);panel2.add(b7);panel2.add(b8);panel2.add(b9);panel2.add(b10);
        add(panel2);
        panel3.add(burger);
        panel3.add(c1);panel3.add(c2);panel3.add(c3);panel3.add(c4);panel3.add(c5);
        panel3.add(c6);panel3.add(c7);panel3.add(c8);panel3.add(c9);panel3.add(c10);
        add(panel3);
        panel4.add(dessert);
        panel4.add(d1);panel4.add(d2);panel4.add(d3);panel4.add(d4);panel4.add(d5);
        panel4.add(d6);panel4.add(d7);panel4.add(d8);panel4.add(d9);panel4.add(d10);
        add(panel4);
        panel5.add(total);panel5.add(compute);panel5.add(exit);
        add(panel5);
        
        setLayout(new GridLayout(1,5,0,0));
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(550,400);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Restaurant Menu");
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxjTh.png)

Comment: Remove `setSize(550,400);` - you window is just to small

Comment: First of all, this: `setSize(550,400);` is bad as it artificially constrains your GUI's size. Instead call `pack()` the GUI (the top-level window, here a JFrame) after adding all components to it and before showing it.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/lPrFdiX here is the output after removing setsize. Do I need to set an layout in each panel so that all of the check boxes will be centered?

Comment: `JPanel` is using a `FlowLayout` by default, maybe `GridLayout(-1, 1)` would produce a more desirable solution, but I'd prefer `GridBagLayout` personally, it will probably produce a more resizable output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `setSize` and let `pack` do its job.  This will "pack" the window around it's child components, based on their preferred layout sizes and the layout managers arrangements, for example...

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Menu beverageMenu = new Menu("Beverages", Arrays.asList(new MenuItem[] {
                    new MenuItem("Coca-Coloa", 1),
                    new MenuItem("Mountain Dew", 1),
                    new MenuItem("Rootbeer", 1),
                    new MenuItem("Fruitsoda", 1),
                    new MenuItem("Royal", 1),
                    new MenuItem("C2", 1),
                    new MenuItem("Mango Shake", 1),
                    new MenuItem("Orange Juice", 1),
                    new MenuItem("Water", 1),
                    new MenuItem("Jack Daniels", 1),
                }));
                Menu snacksMenu = new Menu("Snacks", Arrays.asList(new MenuItem[] {
                    new MenuItem("Popcorn", 1),
                    new MenuItem("Potato chips", 1),
                    new MenuItem("Fries", 1),
                    new MenuItem("Chips 4", 1),
                    new MenuItem("Yogurt 5", 1),
                    new MenuItem("String chees 6", 1),
                    new MenuItem("Cereal 7", 1),
                    new MenuItem("Granola bars 8", 1),
                    new MenuItem("Gummy bears 9", 1),
                    new MenuItem("Pretzels 10", 1),
                }));
                Menu burgerMenu = new Menu("Burgers", Arrays.asList(new MenuItem[] {
                    new MenuItem("Double pattey burger", 1),
                    new MenuItem("Cheese burger 2", 1),
                    new MenuItem("Baacon burger", 1),
                    new MenuItem("Cheese & bacon burger", 1),
                    new MenuItem("Mushroom burger", 1),
                    new MenuItem("Pepperoni burger", 1),
                    new MenuItem("Quater-pound burger", 1),
                    new MenuItem("Spicy burger", 1),
                    new MenuItem("Chicken burger", 1),
                    new MenuItem("Pizza burger", 1),
                }));
                Menu dessertMenu = new Menu("Deserts", Arrays.asList(new MenuItem[] {
                    new MenuItem("Cacke", 1),
                    new MenuItem("Ice cream", 1),
                    new MenuItem("Cookies", 1),
                    new MenuItem("Lech flan", 1),
                    new MenuItem("Ube", 1),
                    new MenuItem("Mango graham", 1),
                    new MenuItem("Macaroons", 1),
                    new MenuItem("Brownies", 1),
                    new MenuItem("Pudding", 1),
                    new MenuItem("Meringue", 1),
                }));

                List<Menu> menus = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new Menu[] {
                    beverageMenu, snacksMenu, burgerMenu, dessertMenu
                }));

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new MainPane(menus));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class MenuItem {
        private String description;
        private double price;

        public MenuItem(String description, double price) {
            this.description = description;
            this.price = price;
        }

        public String getDescription() {
            return description;
        }

        public double getPrice() {
            return price;
        }        
    }

    public class Menu {
        private String title;
        private List<MenuItem> items;

        public Menu(String title, List<MenuItem> items) {
            this.title = title;
            this.items = items;
        }

        public List<MenuItem> getItems() {
            return items;
        }

        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }
    }

    public class MainPane extends JPanel {
        public MainPane(List<Menu> menus) {
            setBorder(new EmptyBorder(4, 4, 4, 4));
            setLayout(new GridLayout(1, -1, 4, 0));

            for (int index = 0; index < menus.size(); index++) {
                Color backgroundColor = index % 2 == 0 ? Color.GRAY : Color.BLUE;
                MenuPane menuPane = new MenuPane(menus.get(index));
                menuPane.setBackground(backgroundColor);
                add(menuPane);
            }

            Color backgroundColor = menus.size() % 2 == 0 ? Color.GRAY : Color.BLUE;

            JPanel actionsPane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            actionsPane.setBackground(backgroundColor);
            GridBagConstraints actionGBC = new GridBagConstraints();
            actionGBC.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

            actionsPane.add(new JLabel("Total: $0.00"), actionGBC);
            actionsPane.add(new JButton("Compute"), actionGBC);
            actionsPane.add(new JButton("Exit"), actionGBC);
            actionGBC.weighty = 1;
            actionsPane.add(new JLabel(), actionGBC);

            add(actionsPane);
        }
    }

    public class MenuPane extends JPanel {
        public MenuPane(Menu menu) {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = gbc.REMAINDER;
            add(new JLabel(menu.getTitle()), gbc);
            for (MenuItem menuItem : menu.getItems()) {
                JCheckBox cb = new JCheckBox(menuItem.getDescription());
                add(cb, gbc);
            }

            gbc.weighty = 1;
            add(new JLabel(), gbc);
        }
    }
}
```

See [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details

---

> Last Question, How do I get the all the item price when if they click compute?

This is where you want to make use of an [observer pattern](https://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html), which can be used to notify interested parties that some state has changed or something of interested has happened, in this case, the user has selected or deselected a `MenuItem`, for example...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Menu beverageMenu = new Menu("Beverages", Arrays.asList(new MenuItem[]{
                    new MenuItem("Coca-Coloa", 1),
                    new MenuItem("Mountain Dew", 1),
                    new MenuItem("Rootbeer", 1),
                    new MenuItem("Fruitsoda", 1),
                    new MenuItem("Royal", 1),
                    new MenuItem("C2", 1),
                    new MenuItem("Mango Shake", 1),
                    new MenuItem("Orange Juice", 1),
                    new MenuItem("Water", 1),
                    new MenuItem("Jack Daniels", 1),}));
                Menu snacksMenu = new Menu("Snacks", Arrays.asList(new MenuItem[]{
                    new MenuItem("Popcorn", 1),
                    new MenuItem("Potato chips", 1),
                    new MenuItem("Fries", 1),
                    new MenuItem("Chips 4", 1),
                    new MenuItem("Yogurt 5", 1),
                    new MenuItem("String chees 6", 1),
                    new MenuItem("Cereal 7", 1),
                    new MenuItem("Granola bars 8", 1),
                    new MenuItem("Gummy bears 9", 1),
                    new MenuItem("Pretzels 10", 1),}));
                Menu burgerMenu = new Menu("Burgers", Arrays.asList(new MenuItem[]{
                    new MenuItem("Double pattey burger", 1),
                    new MenuItem("Cheese burger 2", 1),
                    new MenuItem("Baacon burger", 1),
                    new MenuItem("Cheese & bacon burger", 1),
                    new MenuItem("Mushroom burger", 1),
                    new MenuItem("Pepperoni burger", 1),
                    new MenuItem("Quater-pound burger", 1),
                    new MenuItem("Spicy burger", 1),
                    new MenuItem("Chicken burger", 1),
                    new MenuItem("Pizza burger", 1),}));
                Menu dessertMenu = new Menu("Deserts", Arrays.asList(new MenuItem[]{
                    new MenuItem("Cacke", 1),
                    new MenuItem("Ice cream", 1),
                    new MenuItem("Cookies", 1),
                    new MenuItem("Lech flan", 1),
                    new MenuItem("Ube", 1),
                    new MenuItem("Mango graham", 1),
                    new MenuItem("Macaroons", 1),
                    new MenuItem("Brownies", 1),
                    new MenuItem("Pudding", 1),
                    new MenuItem("Meringue", 1),}));

                List<Menu> menus = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new Menu[]{
                    beverageMenu, snacksMenu, burgerMenu, dessertMenu
                }));

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new MainPane(menus));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class MenuItem {
        private String description;
        private double price;

        public MenuItem(String description, double price) {
            this.description = description;
            this.price = price;
        }

        public String getDescription() {
            return description;
        }

        public double getPrice() {
            return price;
        }
    }

    public class Menu {
        private String title;
        private List<MenuItem> items;

        public Menu(String title, List<MenuItem> items) {
            this.title = title;
            this.items = items;
        }

        public List<MenuItem> getItems() {
            return items;
        }

        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }
    }

    public class MainPane extends JPanel {
        private CheckOutPane checkOutPane;
        public MainPane(List<Menu> menus) {
            setBorder(new EmptyBorder(4, 4, 4, 4));
            setLayout(new GridLayout(1, -1, 4, 0));

            for (int index = 0; index < menus.size(); index++) {
                Color backgroundColor = index % 2 == 0 ? Color.GRAY : Color.BLUE;
                MenuPane menuPane = new MenuPane(menus.get(index), new MenuPane.Observer() {
                    @Override
                    public void menuDidSelectItem(MenuPane source, MenuItem menuItem) {
                        checkOutPane.addMenuItem(menuItem);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void menuDidDeselectItem(MenuPane source, MenuItem menuItem) {
                        checkOutPane.removeMenuItem(menuItem);
                    }
                });
                menuPane.setBackground(backgroundColor);
                add(menuPane);
            }

            Color backgroundColor = menus.size() % 2 == 0 ? Color.GRAY : Color.BLUE;
            checkOutPane = new CheckOutPane();
            checkOutPane.setBackground(backgroundColor);
            add(checkOutPane);
        }
    }

    public class CheckOutPane extends JPanel {
        private double runningTally = 0;
        private JLabel tallyLabel;
        private List<MenuItem> basket;

        public CheckOutPane() {
            basket = new ArrayList<>(8);
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

            tallyLabel = new JLabel("Total: $0.00");

            add(tallyLabel, gbc);
            add(new JButton("Compute"), gbc);
            add(new JButton("Exit"), gbc);
            gbc.weighty = 1;
            add(new JLabel(), gbc);

            updateTally();
        }

        public double getOrderTotal() {
            return runningTally;
        }

        public List<MenuItem> getBasket() {
            return basket;
        }

        protected void updateTally() {
            tallyLabel.setText("Total: " + NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(getOrderTotal()));
        }

        public void addMenuItem(MenuItem menuItem) {
            basket.add(menuItem);
            runningTally += menuItem.getPrice();
            updateTally();
        }

        public void removeMenuItem(MenuItem menuItem) {
            if (basket.contains(menuItem)) {
                basket.remove(menuItem);
                runningTally -= menuItem.getPrice();
                updateTally();
            }
        }
    }

    public class MenuPane extends JPanel {
        public interface Observer {
            public void menuDidSelectItem(MenuPane source, MenuItem menuItem);
            public void menuDidDeselectItem(MenuPane source, MenuItem menuItem);
        }
        private Observer observer;
        public MenuPane(Menu menu, Observer observer) {
            this.observer = observer;
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = gbc.REMAINDER;
            add(new JLabel(menu.getTitle()), gbc);
            for (MenuItem menuItem : menu.getItems()) {
                JCheckBox cb = new JCheckBox(menuItem.getDescription());
                cb.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        if (cb.isSelected()) {
                            observer.menuDidSelectItem(MenuPane.this, menuItem);
                        } else {
                            observer.menuDidDeselectItem(MenuPane.this, menuItem);
                        }
                    }
                });
                add(cb, gbc);
            }

            gbc.weighty = 1;
            add(new JLabel(), gbc);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Last Question, How do I get the all the item price when if they click compute?

Comment: This is where you need an observer pattern.  So, I'd create a `MenuObserver` `interface` with methods something along the lines of `menuDidSelect(Menu source, MenuItem menuItem)` and `menuDidDeselect(Menu source, MenuItem menuItem)`.  This would need to be passed and managed by the `MenuPane`, so that when ever a `JCheckBox` was actioned, it could use the observer to notify any interested parties (ie the `MainPane`), which would then keep track of all the items selected and update it's UI (ie the total)

Comment: Thank you so much on this one! I really appreciate your help and also thanks for explaining it to me :)